# What does "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" do?

Tags: command-line, apt

I would like to know more about this command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

See `man apt-get`:

```
 dist-upgrade
           dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing
           dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will
           attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. The
           dist-upgrade command may therefore remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of
           locations from which to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for
           overriding the general settings for individual packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

To learn about commands, read their manual page (short "manpage") using the `man` command.

E.g. to learn about `apt-get`, type this command:

```
man apt-get
```

The manual will also contain a description of the `dist-upgrade` argument:

```
   dist-upgrade
       dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
       also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
       of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
       it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
       expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade
       command may therefore remove some packages. The
       /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which
       to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for
       a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual
       packages.
```

To exit the manual viewer again, simply press <kbd>Q</kbd>.

The `sudo` is needed because the command needs root privileges in order to perform the necessary system-wide operations.